# ES6 - Create new object from existing data, using only one property, and removing any duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects being returned to me as `data`, I'm looking to Create a new set of data, while retaining the old one for future use.

I'm trying to loop through the data given to create a new set of data that only contains age, but also removes any duplicates.  I'm not too sure where to start with this.

```
data = [
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "age": "99"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName": "Jimmy",
        "lastName": "Hendricks",
        "age": "50"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName": "William",
        "lastName": "Shakespeare",
        "age": "22"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Eyre",
        "age": "50"
    }
]
```

What I'd like to end up with is something like this:

```
newData = [
        {"age": "99"}, 
        {"age": "50"}, 
        {"age": "22"}
]
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: You could just loop over `data` extracting the age and make a check if you added it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can just use `Set` for eliminating duplicates:

```
// ages variable contain just the ages
const ages = data.map(person => person.age);
// new Set(ages) will remove duplicated values:
const newSet = Array.from(new Set(ages)).map(age => ({ age: age }));
```

Comment: Really concise, makes perfect sense too!  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Wow, so many approaches!
Here is another one, purely functional:

```js
data = [ { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "age": "99" }, { "firstName": "Jimmy", "lastName": "Hendricks", "age": "50" }, { "firstName": "William", "lastName": "Shakespeare", "age": "22" }, { "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Eyre", "age": "50" } ]; 

console.log(
 Object.keys(data.reduce((obj,o)=>
      (obj[o.age]=1,obj),{}))
.map(k=>({age:k}))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let newData = [];
let uniques = [];
data.forEach(el => {
    if(!uniques.includes(el.age)){
      newData.push({age: el.age});
      uniques.push(el.age);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for this:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "age": "99"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName": "Jimmy",
        "lastName": "Hendricks",
        "age": "50"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName": "William",
        "lastName": "Shakespeare",
        "age": "22"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Eyre",
        "age": "50"
    }
]

const newdata = data
  .map(({age}) => ({age})) // convert `{age: <value of age>}`
  .filter(function({age}) {
    const isUnique = !this.has(age); //check if already present
    this.add(age); //add anyway

    return isUnique; //filter keeping uniques
  }, new Set());//use a Set as the `this` context for the filter
  
console.log(newdata);
```